# Compiling with g++ and having GraphicsMagick++ as static library

Tags: c++, g++, imagemagick, static-libraries, static-linking

The following command works

```
g++ file.cpp $( GraphicsMagick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs )
```

but i want a static executable that is not linked to the library, so i have tried

```
g++ file.cpp $( GraphicsMagick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs ) -static
```

but it only generates the following errors

```
/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `__DTOR_END__' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/crtbeginT.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

adding `-fPIC` gives the same result.

I'm using the GraphicsMagick++ version that comes with the standard repository in Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Since GraphicsMagick++ is a fork of ImageMagick some old trick for ImageMagick will probably work but i have never used ImageMagick, only GraphicsMagick++.

Answer (score 0):

To link statically against that particular library, use `-Wl,-Bstatic` *before* it, i.e.:

```
g++ $( GraphicsMagick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags ) -fPIC file.cpp -o file -Wl,-Bstatic $( GraphicsMagick++-config --ldflags --libs )
```

If you then wanted to pass more libraries, and link dynamically against them, you can pass `-Wl,-Bdynamic` to switch back and add more libraries afterwards.

*Edit*: Also note the specific argument order. First compiler flags, then file, then linker flags and libraries at the end. With other order, you can run into random failures. Really.

Comment: nope, your exact command gives me this `/usr/bin/ld.bfd.real: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.a(ftinit.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `tt_driver_class' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: Tried with `-fPIC`? You need to pass it before the filename. Well, give me a minute and I'll stop being lazy and show you the correct argument order for the compiler.

Comment: nope again, `-fPIC` solves nothing and the output is still the same :/

Comment: Ai, I start to suspect that the Ubuntu static library is simply broken…

Comment: so i have to recompile GM++ from its source and give up with this version?

Comment: also, can you be more specific about the problem that this package is having ?

Comment: No, not GM++. If I understand the linker correctly, it is saying that static *libfreetype* should have been compiled with `-fPIC` (and it wasn't). But I might be wrong.